# Meaning of "stars being already dead when we look at them" in relativity

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, speed-of-light, coordinate-systems, observers

It is a very common statement that when we look at a star, it might already be dead because its light took time to arrive to us.

But I am puzzled by this statement, since it seems to assume that we can give a meaning to "the star is presently dead", although relativity tells us that we should not trust our intuitions about existence of an absolute time or an absolute notion of simultaneity.

My question is: to what extent this classic statement makes sense ? Are we omitting relativistic effects because they are still negligible at this scale ? Are there several layers of approximations, for instance accounting for special relativity, then for general relativity ?

Comment: You're completely right. As long as we haven't seen the star die yet, there's a frame whose origin coincides with ours in which the star *isn't* dead yet. Nonetheless, the statement still has meaning, if we always judge simultaneity in terms of our familiar Earth frame.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the Sun for simplicity. If it exploded 8 minutes ago (in my stationary Earth frame--I am on Earth right now), I can look at it for 8 more minutes an say "It may already be dead" before getting the bad news.

That's doesn't have anything to do with special relativity (SR), rather it depends on the finite speed of the propagation of light.

SR comes into play because the event "now on earth" and "sun explodes" have a space-like separation, so they can not be time-ordered uniquely.

While I say "now" is the time at which the sun exploded, someone westbound at sunset on a relativistic TGV would say it happened a while ago, and someone eastbound would say it hasn't happened yet, and all three of us would be right.

Comment: Thanks, you seem to hint that indeed different observers on Earth may disagree on the "now".  But probably, even taking into account the speed of the sun in the Milky way, this is negligible in practice and all possible "now" on earth will agree on whether a star is dead now. Is this correct ?

Comment: The speed of the sun doesn't affect my definition of now (also called: hyperplane-of-simultenaety). The effect I described is called "The Andromeda Paradox", where even human-achievable velocities affect whether an event is in the past or future. You simply cannot uniquely time-order 2 events with space-like separation, but that is not a problem, since you can never know anything outside you light cone. Ever.

Comment: ok, so the meaning of "now" for distant stars from our perspective might indeed be affected by this, if I understand correctly. When I was talking about the speed of the sun in the galaxy, it was in the sense that we are following it and we might want to incorporate it in our speed when observing distant stars or galaxies.